# location.hash is not changing to the previous hash on the first click of browser back button but only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, hash

I have a backbone route application in which some page are loading through ajax,
my home page url is ending like 1)home.shtml, and i have account settings page and url is 2)settings.shtml#/account_settings, one more is 3)settings.shtml#/preferences

When i navigating from page 1 to 2 and click the back button everything is working fine.
but when i navigating form page 2 to 3 (which is loading through ajax call-no page reload) and click on back button the hash url is still #/preferences and page doesn't loading. but if i click one more time the hash is changing to #/account_settings and page is getting loaded.

Comment: Is Backbone.history.start() initiated?

Comment: yes.. i have called Backbone.history.start() ;

Comment: Well then it means in backbone history url hash is not changed. Its a bit hard to comment without looking at actual code.